# json validation not working?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am trying to validate my json through schemavalidation but I think there are some issues:

```
string schemaJson = @"
{
    'description': 'A payload',
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'totalRecords': {'type':'number'},
        'payload': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {'name':{'type':'string'}}
        }
    },
    'additionalProperties': false
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
JObject payl = JObject.Parse(@"
{
    'totalRecords': 75,
    'payload':{'namdse':'ksjfkjsdkfjkd'}
}");

IList<string> messages;
bool valid = payl.IsValid(schema, out messages);

Console.WriteLine(valid);

foreach (string message in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

The console returns `true` but it should return `false` because I am using the wrong property name `namdse` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `additionalProperties` to `false` in your `payload` properties.

```
...
'payload': {
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name':{'type':'string'}        
  },
  'additionalProperties': false
}
...
```

Your json is valid because `namdse` is being considered as additional property. And if `name` is a required field, you might need to add the `required` keyword also.

```
...
'payload': {
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name':{'type':'string', 'required': true}        
  },
  'additionalProperties': false
}
...
```

Comment: Additionally, he might want to set all properties as `required` since they are all optional by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object is invalid json, use double quotes, this is valid in http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
"description": "A payload",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "totalRecords": {
        "type": 123
    },
    "payload": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
},
"additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: FYI, json.net will accept either single- or double-quotes for strings. It should still parse fine.

Comment: I don't doubt you, but why both validators fail using single quotes http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ,  http://jsonlint.com/, any one know ?

Comment: My point is, the code uses json.net to parse the string which will accept it. Whether or not the same string will parse using a different parser doesn't matter.